# Replace Teamviewer default icon to a monochrome one

Tags: icons, teamviewer, tweak

Teamviewer now is a native Linux app, but the panel icon isn't integrated with the monochrome icons like i.e. Dropbox
[image]

Is there a way to fix it? I searched on the Teamviewer forums but no luck.
I'm on 18.04 LTS & Gnome 3 and the Ubuntu Mono default icons

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Hardcode-Tray](https://github.com/bilelmoussaoui/Hardcode-Tray) to fix the issue with colourful tray icons. Currently it supports only the Numix and Papirus icon themes (actually, you can manage any icon icon theme to work with Hardcode-Tray, see below<sup>1</sup>).

You can install it from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~andreas-angerer89/+archive/ubuntu/sni-qt-patched) by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andreas-angerer89/sni-qt-patched
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sni-qt hardcode-tray
```

Then run `hardcode-tray` by

```
sudo -E hardcode-tray
```

and it will give you an option to "fix" the tray icons.

---

1. *A [note from the developer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041271/replace-teamviewer-default-icon-to-a-monochrome-one/1041284?noredirect=1#comment1866536_1041284) of Hardcode-Tray:*

   > You can use whatever theme you like as soon as the theme supports the app you want to fix. We detect which icons the theme has and get the ones we need for each app. so if you create a new theme called for example "Test" with the icons you need, you can use that by passing `--theme` argument. You don't need to use that theme in order to use it to fix your hardcoded icons, you can use whatever theme you like, if the colors doesn't match your color, we have already an argument to change the colors during the process too.

Comment: Numix does it. It looks great, but I wonder if there is a way to manually fix it with the default Ubuntu Mono icons. I don't like the Numix icon set :(

Comment: Hey, Hardcode-tray developer here. You can use whatever theme you like as soon as the theme supports the app you want to fix. We detect which icons the theme has and get the ones we need for each app. so if you create a new theme called for example "Test" with the icons you need, you can use that by passing --theme argument. You don't need to use that theme in order to use it to fix your hardcoded icons, you can use whatever theme you like, if the colors doesn't match your color, we have already an argument to change the colors during the process too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bilal for the update, I have appended it to the answer.